# Counting DNA nucleotides in C

Tags: c, beginner, bioinformatics

I have written code to solve the following [Rosalind problem](http://rosalind.info/problems/dna/). This is my first time writing in C and I would like a review of my code, particularly in regard to correctness and performance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {

    /* Input DNA of length at most 1000 nucleotides */
    char dna[1000];
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen("/Users/James/Desktop/rosalind_dna.txt", "r");
    fgets(dna, 1000, input);
    fclose(input);

    /* Count frequency of symbols 'A', 'C', 'G' and 'T' in DNA */
    int i, a, c, g, t;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(dna); i++) {
        if (dna[i] == 'A') {
            a += 1;
        }
        else if (dna[i] == 'C') {
            c += 1;
        }
        else if (dna[i] == 'G') {
            g += 1;
        }
        else if (dna[i] == 'T') {
            t += 1;
        }
    }

    /* Output frequency of DNA nucleotides */
    printf("%i %i %i %i", a, c, g, t);
    return 0;
}
```

**Updated Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define READ_BUFFER_SIZE 1000

int main() {

    /* Input DNA of length at most 1000 nucleotides */
    char dna[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
    FILE *input;    
    input = fopen("/Users/James/Desktop/rosalind_dna.txt", "r");
    if (input == NULL) {
        perror("Error");
    }
    fgets(dna, READ_BUFFER_SIZE, input);
    fclose(input);

    /* Count frequency of symbols 'A', 'C', 'G' and 'T' in DNA */
    int aCount, cCount, gCount, tCount;
    char *current;
    for(current = dna; *current; ++current) {
        switch(*current){
            case 'A':
                ++aCount;
                break;
            case 'C':
                ++cCount;
                break;
            case 'G':
                ++gCount;
                break;
            case 'T':
                ++tCount;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Error: Invalid nucleotide\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    /* Output frequency of DNA nucleotides */
    printf("%i %i %i %i", aCount, cCount, gCount, tCount);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am no C programmer but there are a few things that come to my eye:

### Static size

You always read at most 1000 characters, what if the file size is much bigger? 
Instead you would loop trough the file, reading/processing it chunkwise.

### Magic Number

Even if you use the static size you should not enter it at multiple locations. Instead use a constant for it to have to apply changes only in one place:

```
#define READ_BUFFER_SIZE 1000
//...
char dna[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
//...
fgets(dna, READ_BUFFER_SIZE, input);
```

### Loop termination

It might be optimized by the compiler but unoptimized your loop end check is n times (for `n = strlen(dna)`) which itself is takes \$O(n)\$, making your loop \$O(n^2)\$.

### Looping

You index through the loop which is more costly than walking a pointer through it like:

```
char *current;
// loop until the '\0' terminator is encountered
for(current = dna; *current; ++current)
```

However, note as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2305783 that modern compiler will optimize the indexed version to the same efficient code as the pointer version.

### Switching

To find the counter for the current base you are using cascading ifs, which is suboptimal. Instead use a switch statement:

```
switch(*current) {
default: assert("Invalid base name!");
case 'A':
//...
```

### Incrementing

This is most likely optimized by the compiler but still: You are incrementing so use the (prefix) increment operator `++a` instead of `a += 1;`.

### Naming

In this short example the names are nearly okay but in a longer program you would want to expand the variable names e.g.:

- `dna` -> `dnaChunkBuffer` (assuming you work in chunks)
- `input` -> `inputFile`
- `i` -> `currentBaseIndex`
- `a`, `c`, `g`, `t` -> `base*Count`

### Code-Reuse

As I said I am no C programmer but I could imagine that there is a standard algorithm which helps you count the different characters in a string. If so, I would go for that.

### Error Handling

It is just a small example but what happens if there is no file at the location you entered? Your program does not account for that. You should at least test if the fopen function succeeded and given an error otherwise.

Comment: Good points ! However, I have serious doubts about the "You index through the loop which is much more costly than walking a pointer through it like" part.

Comment: @Josay: Can you expand on this? In my experience indexing is slower (when unoptimized) because it uses the formula `baseAddress + sizeof(element) * index` (and increments the index) whereas incrementing a pointer does not need this calculation. So indexing has one more addition and one more multiplication.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: You are right. I discarded this when writing the code but I don't remember why.

Comment: The "looping" section is not completely correct, indexing an array is substantially as cheap as working with pointers. The real problem is that he is potentially calling `strlen` at each iteration, which is O(n) in the length of the string, thus making the whole thing O(n^2). Also in your example `strlen` isn't needed (you walk the array twice for no reason), just do `for(current = dna; *current; ++current)`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I am not sure you understood me correctly. On the performance of indexing vs pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2305783 However, I was talking about unoptimized code.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful suggestions everyone! Could you elaborate on the use of `for(current = dan; *current; ++ current)`? I'm currently working out by hand what the variables will contain and what the for loop is iterating over and I'm slightly at a loss.

Comment: @jma1991: `current` is a pointer to the currently tested base lette. The loop does the same as your indexed loop but does not use indexing but the pointer. `*current` gets the currently pointed to value (so the loop condition is "is the current value unequal to zero (the string terminator). `++current` will move the pointer to the next element in the array.

Comment: @Nobody: sorry, I deleted the first comment (and added the second) while you were posting yours, so there has been some miscommunication. For the indexes vs pointers thing, talking about performance makes sense only in optimized builds, and even in unoptimized builds the performance difference will be within experimental error. An `add` to a register - or even better, an access via base+index directly in the `mov` instruction - is negligible compared to accessing memory.

Comment: From your answer, my understanding of the loop is thus: 

Say the DNA variable contains "ACGT" at the memory address 1000 - when the pointer is incremented it will now refer to memory address 1001 which is the second character of the DNA variable?

Could you clarify if this is correct?

Thank you.

Comment: @jma1991: Exactly.

Answer (score 6):

The Rosalind problem takes in a string and counts the occurrences of A,C,G,T - reading the string from the file is not part of it so I shall skip over that.

In terms of correctness - does what is intended - it seems fine.

In terms of performance, as @Nobody mentioned, it is most likely that `strlen()` is being called multiple times, so doing it once outside the loop and using the saved value is a better plan (a compiler my optimize it out but I wouldn't rely on it)

If performance is/becomes an issue you might try removing the `if`/`else`/`else` setup by creating an array of values and indexing into them, but truthfully this is just messing around. For this situation the difference in performance would be negligible.

```
/* 20 slots, because we only need up as far as T */
int results[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int strLen = strlen(inputString);
for (int index = 0; index < strLen; index++){
    results[inputString[index] - 'A']++;
}

aCount = results[0];
cCount = results['C'-'A'];
gCount = results['G'-'A'];
tCount = results['T'-'A'];
```

**Other Points**

It is a matter of personal preference but once I move above 3 options I tend to go for a `select()` rather than the if/else/else

```
int strLen = strlen(inputString);

for (int index = 0; index < strLen; index++){
    switch (inputString[index]){
        case 'A':
            aCount++;
            break;
        case 'C':
            cCount++;
            break;
        case 'G':
            gCount++;
            break;
        case 'T':
            tCount++;
            break;
    }
}
```

as it can be a bit easier to follow but this will not impact correctness and AFAIK it does not have better performance than `if` / `else` / `else`.

Answer (score 5):

While the revised version is better, I worry about the 1000 nucleotides limitation. If you ever want to operate on a larger data set, your memory allocation will fail.

It would be better to not buffer it in ram, as the file system already has numerous buffers.

I would change the loop to a:

```
while (c=fgetc(input))
```

then use an array of 4 for the sums:

```
unsigned int nucleotides[4];
int n; /* index into nucleotides, per the switch below: 0=a, 1=c, 2=g, 3=t*/
```

then index into the nucleotides and increment as:

```
switch (c)
{
    case 'A': n=0; break;
    case 'C': n=1; break;
    case 'G': n=2; break;
    case 'T': n=3; break;
}
nucleotides[n]++;
```

Finally after the loop:

```
printf("%i %i %i %i", nucleotides[0], nucleotides[1], nucleotides[2], nucleotides[3]);
return 0;
```

This will result in a program that is very light on ram, and doesn't spend a lot of time in `strlen();` You can successfully run this version as long as there aren't more than 4 billion samples of a nucleotide. If there are more, then change the type of nucleotides to `long long`.

To make it slightly more readable you can use an `enum` or `#define` to map the indexes `0..3` to `A..T` respectively.